# how ro remove child objects from a canvas those child objects are added dynamically to the canvas

Tags: c#, silverlight, canvas, silverlight-5.0

I am dynamically adding a Rectangle object to a canvas `DrawImageTest` as mentioned below:

```
System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle rectToDraw  = ToRectangle(rect);
DrawImageTest.Children.Add(rectToDraw);
```

Could you please tell me how to remove this `rectToDraw` rectangle object from `Canvas` dynamically through code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you still have the reference to `rectToDraw`you just have to use :

```
DrawImageTest.Children.Remove(rectToDraw);
```

Comment: Thank you Anders and Laurent, i modified rectToDraw as a public member with class scope then i used DrawImageTest.Children.Remove(rectToDraw);
 wherever i need. Thank you guys...